# How do I install Windows 8 using a GPT Partition scheme?

Tags: windows-8, multi-boot, arch-linux, uefi, gpt

This question seems to have been asked in very similar form in the past, but I was unable to find a relevant answer her or elsewhere.

I am ultimately looking to install a dual boot of x64 Windows 8 and Arch Linux on my machine. According to [this Arch Wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Partitioning#Choosing_between_GPT_and_MBR), x64 Windows 8 booted with UEFI requires a GPT partition scheme for the dual boot to work.

After checking, it was clear the system was using an MBR partition scheme.I used

I suspected the machine was booting using UEFI: when I booted up the Arch install media (I am using usb), I found that the directory `/etc/firmware/efi` existed.

Since an MBR/UEFI is precisely what the Arch page says what won't work, I tried to re-install Windows, attempting to change the disk to GPT (though I failed): I used `gdisk` in the arch install media to convert the partition table to GPT and then installed Windows 8, but is seems the installation process replaced the GPT with an MBR--Windows utilities indicated the disk was MBR formatted.

Frustrated, I decided to try to install Arch anyways, in the belief that maybe the machine wasn't actually booting with UEFI. After completing the install, and using GRUB as bootloader, the machine booted to a Windows error screen, with

```
File: \Windows\system32\winload.exe
Error code: 0xc000000e
```

in the error.

I am using a Samsung Series 9 laptop for this process, model `NP900X4C-A01US`.

My machine has a UEFI option in the BIOS' boot menu (and it is enabled), but the menu item writes,

> 'Enabled' means the system can boot Legacy OS or UEFI OS. 'Disabled' means the system can boot Legacy OS only.

As a result, I thought the system on my machine was possibly using BIOS instead of UEFI to boot, but it seems this hypothesis didn't pan out.

I'd be happy to provide any other information.

Comment: You need to boot the Windows Installation disk in UEFI mode.  You should be able to specific tell your system to load UEFI media only.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: That depends on what motherboard you have.

Answer (score 0):

You could try downloading a CD-R or USB flash drive version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) (If your Windows installer is on an optical disc, you'll need to use the USB flash drive version of rEFInd.) Prepare a medium and boot to it, with your Windows installation medium also attached/installed. rEFInd should show you options to boot to the Windows installer. If it doesn't, wait a few seconds and hit the Esc key. The default configuration for rEFInd on UEFI-based PCs is to show only EFI boot options, so you can be sure that you'll boot the Windows installer in EFI mode if you do this.